# How to add recharts to react-pdf

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, recharts, react-pdf

I am using '**recharts**' to create graphs for my project,
and '**react-pdf**' for generating a report.
'**Recharts**' creates a svg on the DOM when using it and a graph is displayed.

Is there a way I can use these two together, and add my '**recharts**' component to my report via react-pdf?
for example - inside a `<Document/>` tag.

[react-pdf link to website](https://react-pdf.org/)

[recharts link to website](https://recharts.org/en-US/)

I have seen a solution which offers to convert the **rechart's** svg to a png, save it locally and then import it and use via `<Image/>` component in react-pdf.

Looking for a more straightforward approach to this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how I solved it :
I have used this article -
https://betterprogramming.pub/heres-why-i-m-replacing-html2canvas-with-html-to-image-in-our-react-app-d8da0b85eadf

It recommends using [html-to-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image) package.

So I've given an id to the container of the rechart component,
and selected it with `docoument.getElementById()`.
Then, used the selected id when querying html-to-image, like so -

```
  const response = await htmlToImage.toPng(myId);
```

The response then contained a url,
which was used as an src for the react-pdf Image component.

Comment: When you say contained a url, did were you saving it somewhere or did the PDF handle dame/png blob? I am trying now, and have generated a blob (so i have the image available on browser, but PDF is ignoring it.

Comment: typo: data:image/png;base64

Comment: The response from htmlToImage has a url. I pushed the url into a local array state. Then, used the url at the Image component which belongs to react-pdf

Comment: Thank you for responding. I found it was because I wasn't awaiting the image callback, so i was generating the PDF before the image existed. So it works now. Thanks again.

Comment: not working for me in the slightest spent a day on this. All i see in the console is

```
arning: Invalid absolute docBaseUrl: "blob:http://localhost:3001/8c31d53a-a264-41eb-aa6c-dbf24f8ce543". pdf.worker.mjs:339:13
PDF 95ee19a179f189a9637ce60e60c5aecf [1.3 react-pdf / react-pdf] (PDF.js: 4.0.67 [5c45dfa0a])
```

Answer (score 3):

I just created https://github.com/EvHaus/react-pdf-charts which allows for `recharts` to be rendered into `react-pdf`. It had only very basic support at the moment, but I'm hoping with some help from the community -- we can get to full support.

Comment: Well done !! Respect :)