# How to Use Chart.js or recharts in react-pdf/renderer

Tags: charts, bar-chart, recharts, react-pdf, react-pdfrenderer

I want to create pdf using react-pdf ,but for charts/graphs i have to use Chart.js or recharts ,but directly i can not implement into react-pdf  , another option i have seen from a qs:
[How to add recharts to react-pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68462413/how-to-add-recharts-to-react-pdf?newreg=9776d19408ea4350bf03510e77219455)

but here html-to-image(   const response = await htmlToImage.toPng(myId)   ) uses but I can not find out how to put that html for docoument.getElementById() and **where** to put that,

I expect to put chart/graph in my created react-pdf pages,In any way.
here html-to-image(   const response = await htmlToImage.toPng(myId)   ) uses but I can not find out how to put that html for docoument.getElementById() and **where** to put that,

Comment: daniel-cohen can you please help me

Comment: Amartya Sarkar, I give an answer if you want to check

Answer (score 2):

To add charts/graphs to your `react-pdf` document, you can convert your chart to an image and then add it to the PDF using an `Image` tag.

Here's how you can do it:

## Step 1: Install the `chartjs-to-image` package

You can use either `chartjs-to-image` or `chartjs-node-canvas` to convert your chart to an image. I prefer to use `chartjs-to-image` because I use Next.js + webpack and `chartjs-node-canvas` doesn't support it.

`npm install chartjs-to-image`

## Step 2: Convert your chart to a base64 image

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Document, Page, Image, View } from '@react-pdf/renderer';
import ChartJsImage from 'chartjs-to-image';

export const MyComponent = () => {
  const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const myChart = new ChartJsImage();
    myChart.setConfig({
      type: 'bar',
      data: { 
        labels: ['Hello world', 'Foo bar'], 
        datasets: [{ label: 'Foo', data: [1, 2] }]
      },
    });
    myChart.toDataUrl().then((data) => setImageSrc(data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <Document>
      <Page>
        <View>
          <Image src={`${imageSrc}`} />
        </View>
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );
};
```

In this example, we're creating a bar chart using `ChartJsImage`, setting its configuration, and then converting it to a base64 image using `toDataUrl()`. We then set the `imageSrc` state to the base64 string so that we can use it in the `Image` tag.